# How to pass form name dynamically in to a javascript method?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass form name dynamically. But this script is showing an error.

**"document.formName is undefined".** How to solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="javascript">

function showAll(form,fieldName) {
    var formName = form.name;
    alert(formName);
    document.formName.search_mode.value = "";   
    document.formName.fieldName.value="";
    document.formName.submit(); 
}
</script>
<form name = "dealsManagement" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="search_mode" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['search_mode'];?>" >
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="400" style="padding:2px; border:#ccc solid 1px; margin:15px auto 15px auto;">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="text3" align="center" height="35" bgcolor="#cccccc">Search</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="153" height="35" align="right" class="text2" style="padding-right:10px;">Search By  City:</td>
<td width="245"><input type="text" name="city" value= "<?php echo $_POST['city']; ?>" size="24" ></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="button" type="button" class="btn" onClick="javascript:dealSearchCity()" value="Search" />
<input name="btnShowAll" type="button" class="btn"value="Show All" onClick="javascript:showAll(this.form,'city');" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: why not just use the form name instead of `this`? Also, have a look at jQuery. That will help you a lot. Have a look here: http://docs.jquery.com , http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/Events/Form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is not necessary. You can use `form` directly:

```
function showAll(form,fieldName) {
    var formName = form.name;
    alert(formName);
    form.elements.search_mode.value = ""; 
    form.elements[fieldName].value="";     
    form.submit(); 
}
```

two sidenotes:

The `language` attribute is deprecated, better use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and you don't need to prefix event handlers with `javascript:`.

Comment: i am trying to use that one js method for multiple forms. I hope now it makes sense

Comment: @Fero it does, but there is still absolutely no need to do what you are doing. If you pass the right `form`, it will work with multiple forms no problem.

Comment: @Pekka "If you pass the right form"-> As i am a newbie i can't understand this statement. Could you please explain.

Comment: @Fero you are passing the form object `this.form` as a parameter to `showAll()`. That already makes the function compatible with multiple forms. There is no need to take the `formName` detour because the form in question is already there. See what I mean?

Comment: @Pekka: If  i use the form then i get [object HTMLFormElement] in alert. If i use the form instead of formName i got the same error. will you please help me out of this issue.

Comment: @Fero what are you trying to do with formName? What do you need it for? And does the code above not work for you?

Comment: @Pekka: i use the same code given by you. But i got the error "form.elements.fieldName is undefined". And my code is not working

Comment: @Fero sorry, my bad. I didn't catch the `fieldName`. I fixed it now, the code above should work.

Comment: @Pekka: Thank you very much Pekka. This is wat the same i wan't thanks a lot.:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a string rather than a literal property name, you have to use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).